# Two containers ping each other but don't connect

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-for-windows

I'm trying to access multiple services from my client side, using REST and WEBSOCKET communication.

For some reason none of the services can talk to each other on a custom network bridge using their container names as host names.
The services work well when the client calls for `localhost`.

Error message example: `MapBox.js:245 GET http://position-provider:5000/api net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

Also when using the command `docker exec frontend ping position-provider -c2` I'm getting this result:

```
--- position-provider ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.071/0.243/0.416 ms
```

And when using
`docker network inspect -f '{{range .Containers}}{{.Name}} {{end}}' mapbox_default`
the two containers are present.

The docker-compose file looks like this:

```
services: 
  position-provider:
    image: prodactive-dev/position-provider
    container_name: position-provider
    ports:
        - '5000:5000'
        - '5001:5001'
    environment:
        - 'ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORT=http://+:5001'
        - 'ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5000'
  mapbox:
    container_name: frontend
    ports:
        - '3000:3000'
    image: mapbox:latest
```

I'm using docker desktop version 3.5.2 on windows 10.

Comment: Your javascript client (running on your localhost) does not know the internal docker network names which are only available from your containers launched from docker-compose. You need to use the portforwarding on localhost. Alternatively you can use your localmachine fqdn or add whatever alias in `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: But my client is having its own container doesn't it (frontend)? So why does it run on localhost anyway?

Comment: Javascript runs in your browser, not in your container